# Can I get the exact location of the image in this url

Tags: url

Is there any way I can get to the url that gets me straight to this image? and how would I get there?

https://catalog.synthes.com/img.ch?systemid=S_TRA_0302.001&type=jpgset&id=682.446

Comment: I can see at least 4 different images on the link you have sent. Which image?

Comment: I suppose it is just one image file right?

Comment: Another example: https://catalog.synthes.com/img.ch?systemid=S_TRA_0412.001&type=jpgpopup&id=04.130.010

Comment: I am not sure I understand, do you want to capture website as a whole and make it a picture? or you want to parse and grab pictures from it? Make sure you are sending correct links.

Comment: Links are correct. My question is if there’s a way to find the url that points directly to the image file. Something like location.com/image.jpg I’m so sorry if this is not any clearer.

Comment: That is weird, i swear I was getting to the Vet website every time i clicked the link. Now I've clicked it again and it opened some medicine kit photo. Also i then used 3rd party tool to download pictures from URL and this tool downloaded 4 pictures that are on the main page of the website...

Comment: Ah :) I actually don’t want to download the pictures. I want to be able to use the actual address to a picture. To use it in power bi (renders the picture from a url)